# CTE in Oracle not working without select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to delete duplicates. But in Oracle Sql developer, when I use the following with CTE, it shows me error. If I use Select it only works then but I want to delete from the table using the view.

```
WITH PECCTE AS ( 
SELECT QT_PEC_RATE.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QT_PEC_RATE.UWC_CODE, AGE ORDER BY QT_PEC_RATE.UWC_CODE) AS ROWNUMBER 
FROM QT_PEC_RATE WHERE NLG_OPTION='STD' AND GENDER='M' AND CNTRY_RATING='C' AND GMCR_RATE=2
)
DELETE FROM PECCTE WHERE ROWNUMBER>1;
```

it shows error that missing select statement.
it only works with  the following

```
WITH PECCTE AS ( 
SELECT QT_PEC_RATE.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QT_PEC_RATE.UWC_CODE, AGE ORDER BY QT_PEC_RATE.UWC_CODE) AS ROWNUMBER 
FROM QT_PEC_RATE WHERE NLG_OPTION='STD' AND GENDER='M' AND CNTRY_RATING='C' AND GMCR_RATE=2
)
SELECT * FROM PECCTE;
```

How can I delete from the table using this view.

Comment: `WHERE ROWNUMBER>1`. Is this a mistake? It should be either `ROWNUM` or `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @Abra `rownumber` is a column alias

Comment: Once again demonstrating the value of good layout. Readability is a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have unique P_ID in the table:

```
DELETE FROM QT_PEC_RATE 
WHERE  P_ID in (
         WITH PECCTE AS ( 
           SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UWC_CODE, AGE ORDER BY UWC_CODE) ROWNUMBER 
           FROM   QT_PEC_RATE 
           WHERE  NLG_OPTION='STD' 
           AND    GENDER='M' 
           AND    CNTRY_RATING='C' 
           AND    GMCR_RATE=2
         )
         SELECT P_ID
         FROM   PECCTE
         WHERE  ROWNUMBER > 1
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work (as you've seen). See if you can rewrite it as

```
delete from peccte
where some_id in (select id 
                  from (select qtpec_rate.*, row_number()... as rownumber   --> this is your CTE
                        from qt_pec_rate
                        where ...
                       )
                  where rownumber > 1
                 );
```